# Ruby on rails thin gem - local server db error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, thin, ruby-1.9.3

When I run rails s on cmd(windows) I got this error below... Can anyone hack this error?
I'm using thin gem for local dev environment. What do I need to chage?

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/config
uration.rb:115:in `read': No such file or directory - C:/Sites/project/config/da
tabase.yml (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/appli
cation/configuration.rb:115:in `database_configuration'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_
record/railtie.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/comma
nds.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the file `C:/Sites/project/config/database.yml` doesn't exist. Either move your `database.yml` to that location, or find the code that expects `database.yml` to be in that location and change it to point to where the file actually is.

Comment: Currently I have three of these on config/locale :
- database.yml.default
- database.yml.mysql
- database.yml.pg

which one should I move?

Comment: The one that has the right settings for the database you are using. If you don't know which database you are using, you need to do some more reading on basic Rails development.